# Breaking a number into two composite numbers.

Tags: prime-numbers

Prove that every natural number $n$ greater than or equal to 12 can be written as a sum of two composite numbers.

Clearly when the number is even, it can be written as a sum of two even composite numbers, but what about when $n$ is odd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An odd number greater than to $12$ can be written as the sum of $9$ and a composite even number.